# Counting a specific char in java

Tags: java, indexing, char, substring, counting

I want to count the number of times a certain character appears in a string, in this case it is the character 'a'. I know I can do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class samsJava {
public static void main(String[] args){

String testStr = "StackoverFlow Guess I'll Test The o's";
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<testStr.length(); i++ ){
    if(testStr.charAt(i) == ('o')){
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of o's:" + counter);
    }
}
```

But what am I doing wrong here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class samsJava {
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Enter String:");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputStr = input.nextLine();
    int counterA = 0;

for(int i = 1; i<inputStr.length(); i++){
    if(inputStr.substring(i - 1, i).equals('a')){
    counterA++;
        }
    }
System.out.println("number of a's:" + counterA);

}
        }
```

Comment: Please include details about what exactly is not working that you want help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substring` is going to return a `String` not a `char`

so change to

```
if(inputStr.substring(i - 1, i).equals("a")){
```

Method one is better though.

Comment: Oh damn, my bad I used (' ') which is reserved for chars, opposed to (" ") for strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No `String` will `.equals('a')` a `char`. You could use `.equals("a")` but I'd prefer a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
for(char ch : inputStr.toCharArray()){
    if (ch == 'a'){
        counterA++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= inputStr.length(); i++)
                  ^
```

or more readable:

`for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i++)` and ...`subString(i, i + 1)`

Comment: This is a  correct answer, he is ignoring the last character!! Thanks for the downvote....

Comment: You are right (+1). It may have been downvoted because of the formatting.